# How do I resolve this type error?

Tags: haskell

I fail to load the following program to GHCi:

```
minList :: Ord a => [a] -> a   
minList (x:[]) = x
minList (x:y:xs) = minList( min x y : xs)

bubList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
bubList [] = []
bubList ( x:y:[] ) = min x y : max x y 
bubList ( x:y:xs ) = minList(x:y:xs) : bubList(xs)
```

When I compile it I get the following error message:

```
   Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for bubList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
      at ex1.hs:11:1
In the second argument of `max', namely `y'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `max x y'
In the expression: min x y : max x y
```

Comment: I hope you see the typo in the third line, `minLiist`

Answer (score 8):

`max x y` will return a value (`a`), not a list (`[a]`). You can only cons (`:`) into a list. You are going to need to write, instead:

```
(min x y : [max x y])
```

Comment: It compiled . Many Thanks, David.

Comment: @DavidKramf You should flag his reply as the Answer :)